# Tem como inserir uma variável passando-a como expressão regular no comando awk?

Tags: regex, linux, variáveis, awk

Exemplo:

`VARIAVEL="Pará"`

`echo "$VARIAVEL" | awk '/^P/ { print $1 }'`

O que isto faz é apenas procurar qualquer palavra iniciada com Letra P maiúscula.

Ok, até aqui tudo bem!

---

Agora, quero saber se tem como inserir esta $VARIAVEL entre as barra da expressão regular do `awk '/$VARIAVEL/ { print $1}'`.?

A intenção é buscar uma única linha de um arquivo.

Este é um modelo do arquivo em questão:

```
Pará                     Norte
Bahia                   Nordeste
Paraná                 Sul
Goiás                   Centro-Oeste
```

.. e assim por diante.

O que tenho feito manualmente é:

ARQUIVO=/tmp/lista_de_estados_brasileiros.txt

`awk '/Bahia/ { print $2 }' $ARQUIVO`

Saída casa com a expressão 'Bahia' da primeira coluna e é retornada a segunda coluna 'Nordeste'.

> Porém quero utilizar-se de uma variável como entrada para *expressão regular* ao invés de ter que digitar manualmente.

Isto é necessário ja que vou utilizar de outro script para selecionar a palavra a ser incluída dentro do `awk`.

Então a pergunta novamente é .. isso é possível? Incluir uma variável dentro da expressão regular do `awk`?

**O Problema aqui é** encontrar um meio para fazer **a inclusão da variável**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você tem que usar `~`, como `$0 ~ variable` o `$1 ~ variable`.

```
awk -v patt="Bahia" '$0 ~ patt {print $2}' fichero
```

Exemplo:

```
$ awk -v patt="Bahia" '$1 ~ patt {print $2}' <<< "Bahia blabla"
blabla
```

Comment: O primeiro exemplo da tua resposta funciona para mim. Fiz assim: `ARQUIVO=/tmp/lista.txt` `awk -v VARIAVEL="Bahia" -F "'" '$0 ~ VARIAVEL {print $2}' $ARQUIVO` e obtive o retorno esperado NORDESTE. Note que estou íncluindo mais um argumento, o -F do qual filtro o conteúdo entre as aspa simples entre os apóstrofos. Porque disto, eu te respondo -, na minha lista a segunda coluna que designa cada região de um estado brasileiro está entre aspas simples 'NORDESTE'. De todo modo seu exemplo foi um breve esclarecimento sobre esta estrutura do awk que não tenho domínio ainda.

Comment: Ja no segundo exemplo: `awk -v patt="Bahia" '$1 ~ patt {print $2}' <<< "Bahia blabla"` ao rodar no terminal [aterm] não obtive êxito [sucesso]. Recebo o seguinte erro: `sh: syntax error: unexpected redirection`. Notei que a minha SHELL esta trabalhando com antigo Bourn Shell. Então como tenho instalado tanto o Sr. Bash como Sr. Bourn. Bastou somente digitar Bash no terminal e em seguida rodar a linha de comando do segundo exemplo da resposta. E assim por fazer, tive retorno mostrado: blabla